# How to allow go to specified page in free jqgrid pager

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jquery-events, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid has page number field. Entering page number to it and pressing enter should invoke specified table.
This stopped to work at some time.
Remote JSON data is used. Entering page number and pressing enter does nothing.

I added `alert(key);` to jqgrid source code as shown in code below before line

https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js#L4045

If <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed, alert box does not appear.
If other keys are pressed, alert box appears.

How to fix this? How to find the reason why enter is ignored? Maybe some other method captures the <kbd>enter</kbd> key and cancels event so that it is not passed to this handler.
How to find this out?

```
if (p.pginput === true) {
    $("input.ui-pg-input", pgcnt).bind("keypress.jqGrid", function (e) {
        var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0, newPage = intNum($(this).val(), 1);
        alert(key); // ADDED
        if (key === 13) {
            if (!clearVals("user", newPage, intNum(p.rowNum, 10))) { return false; }
            $(this).val(newPage);
            p.page = ($(this).val() > 0) ? $(this).val() : p.page;
            populate.call(ts);
            return false;
        }
        return this;
    });
}
```

**Update**

Chrome developer tools shows the following listeners. How to find which blocks the <kbd>enter</kbd> key?

[image]

Comment: Which version of free jqGrid you use? Just try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/glyphicon.htm), which I prepared for your previous question. Yo do can set 1 or 2 in the input field for the pager and press Enter to change the page.

Comment: `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` contains `Date: 2015-07-24`. Your demo works but application does not. I looked into this input element listeners in Chrome Developer Tools but they all point to jquery source code. How to debug the issue ? I can create test page and provide link.

Comment: @Oleg. Application code contains `$("html").keydown(function (evt) {
    return htmlKeydown(evt);
});` Adding alert before return does not show message box on enter but shows on other keys pressed in this input element

Comment: Do you try to change (at least temporary) the URL to free jqGrid files to use the latest source from GitHub or the version 4.9.2 (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). I remind about some close bug, but I can't remember the exact fix. The problem was somewhere with unbinding, but **not** in the place which you included in the text of your question. The versions 4.9.1 and 4.9.2 almost don't contains new features, just bug fixes. So I would recommend you to

Comment: I replaced jquery.jqgrid.src.js from todays github with file which has Date: 2015-08-10 . Problem persists. I updated question and provided chrome developer tools output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the problem exist not in free jqGrid. I guess that some other handle of `keydown` which you registered returns `false` (or in some other way like `e.preventDefault()`), which prevent processing of other `keydown` *and* processing of `<kbd>Enter</kbd>` key. To be sure one has to debug all registered `keydown` and `keydown` handlers.

**UPDATED:** I suppose that you move the pager input field inside of navigator bar (as I remember your old questions). As the result the <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the pager input will be replaced to the `click`.

```
$focused = $(this).find(":focus");
if ($focused.length > 0) {
    $focused.trigger("click");
    return false;
}
```

**The problem is not exist in the standard navigator bar. It is exist only after your customization of the navigator bar**. Nevertheless I posted today [the changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/b5a5f190c2eb699aeac1440dbcfb6bed3d441fdc) which modifies the line `$focused = $(this).find(":focus");` to

```
$focused = $(this).find(".ui-pg-button").filter(":focus");
```

It makes no effects in the standard navigator of the free jqGrid, but it can solve the problem which exists after your customization of the navigator bar.

Comment: How to debug all registered handlers? How to place breakpoint to first handler and step into their code ?

Comment: @Andrus: Sorry, but the answer is too long for the comment. I think that you have found already all palaces with JavaScript code where `keypress`, `keydown` and `keyup` are registered in your code. If you not yet localize the places then `$._data($("input.ui-pg-input")[0], "events")` could help you to localize there. You should type in the input box of the pager new page number, then set/enable breakpoints on all suspected places and finally press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and to debug the code. The most important will be the places with `return false;` and calls of fictions like `.preventDefault()`.

Comment: All handlers point to single jquery source line line as shown in question. Stepping by F11 near this line in Chrome runs code only inside jQuery, external event handlers are not called.
It looks like jQuery tries to find focused element but fails for unknown reason and thus does not invoke keydown event handlers or meybe using Chrome debugger removes focus from it. Pressing Enter in inline edit works OK so this may relate to jqgrid for this particular input element.
How to debug or fix this ?

Comment: @Andrus: You can verify that `$._data($("input.ui-pg-input")[0], "events").keypress[0].handler` shows the code of free jqGrid which starts with "function (e) { var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0, newPage = intNum($(this).val(), 1); if (key === 13) { if (!clearVals("user", newPage, intNum(p.rowNum, 10))) { return false; } $(this).val(newPage); p.page =". So one do can see the code of the handler. I suppose that you registered `keydown` or `keyup` in your code which stop processing of Enter key and so the `keypress` event will be not generated. I can't explain you shortly how to use gebugger

Comment: I verified in Chrome console that this `$._data($("input.ui-pg-input")[0], "events").keypress[0].handler` contains code in your comment. So it looks like that this code is not called by jquery. How to force jquery to call it ? Is it possible to add direct handler without jquery wrapper?

Comment: @Andrus: I wrote you before that I suppose that the reason of the problem is **another part of your code**. I suppose that `keydown` or `keyup` handlers of **your program** is the reason of the problem. So you can look the code fragment in `$._data($("input.ui-pg-input")[0], "events").keyup[0].handler`, `$._data($("input.ui-pg-input")[0], "events").keydown[0].handler`, `$._data($("input.ui-pg-input")[0], "events").keydown[1].handler`, `$._data($("input.ui-pg-input")[0], "events").keydown[2].handler` and so on and to find the code **in your program**, set the breakpoints in the code and debug.

Comment: @Andrus: You wrote before that you see that all handlers point into the code of jQuery und you asked how to debug the code. With my previous comment I have shown only that one can do see the code of the handler which is not inside of jQuery and which code you can see, localize and debug it.

Comment: `$._data($("input.ui-pg-input")[0], "events")` does not have keyup and keydown properties (it has only keypress). How I can look into code fragment if those properties do not exist ?

Comment: @Andrus: Sorry, but I can't post you universal instructions how to debug event handler.

Comment: removing line 11942 `return false;` in https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js#L11942  enables enter to work again. How to make enter work without modifying jqgrid source code?

Comment: @Andrus: I suppose the problem exist because you moved the pager input inside of navigator toolbar. The default code have pager input **outside of** navigator bar. So the problem don't exist. I will look in the code to see how it could be changes so, that you will not such problems and one still be able to use keyboard for navigation and activation of the navigator buttons.

Comment: @Andrus: I posted [the changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/b5a5f190c2eb699aeac1440dbcfb6bed3d441fdc) and I posted **UPDATED** part of my answer. I hope that you will have no described problems if you would use the latest sources from GitHub.

Comment: @Oleg thanks once again for your continuous support here on SO. I was expecting to find an error somewhere in my JS code (infact, the error was lurking there ...) but thanks to your answer here I found it was because of a global keydown handler I had defined somewhere else. OT: Sorry for the OT comment :-)

Comment: @SaschaM78: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you. I see you are leaving not far from me. It's nice to meat here not only the people from another side of the earth. :-)